# Working out modulo of negative powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Say we have the following: $3^{-1}\bmod 7$, how do we calculate this without a calculator? I was gonna do $3^1 \bmod 7 = 3$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You could use the extended Euclidean algorithm, but for such small numbers you could try multiplying all the residues modulo $7$ by $3$ to see which one gives you $1\pmod 7$, and that one is $3^{-1}$

Comment: Remember that $3^{-1}$ means “the number that multiplied by $3$ yields $1$”. So you are trying to solve $3x\equiv 1\pmod{7}$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner how would I do Extended Euclidean Algorithm (EEA) please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Euclidean division $7=3\times2+1,$ we can see that $1=7+3\times-2$.

Modulo $7$, this reads $1\equiv3\times-2,$ or $1\equiv3\times5$;

this indicates that $-2$ or $5$ is the inverse of $3$ modulo $7$.

Comment: Actually, $-2$ or $5$ modulo $7$ are same so you don't need to say the same answer twice

Comment: You are correct @IsaacYIUMathStudio that there is only one inverse, which can be represented as $-2$ or $5$

Comment: Check:   $3\times5=15\equiv1 \pmod 7$ and $3\times-2=-6\equiv1\pmod7$

Comment: I know this... but I think you can just say one of the answer and not two because it is unnecessary to show two **same** answer

Comment: Thank you so much! I have accepted this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Even in modular arithmetic, it is true that $3^{-1} \cdot 3^1 = 1$

So you just need to find a value $x$ such that $3 \cdot x = 1$. Fortunately, you only have 7 options to check in mod 7.
$x$ could equal $0,1,2,3,4,5$ or $6$

Answer (score 0):

If you weren't a beginner, we could do it as follows:

$${(7-1)\over 3}=2\therefore 3\cdot(7-2)\equiv 1\bmod 7$$  This reads as, subtracting 1 from 7 and dividing by 3 gives you 2. Therefore, 3 times the number created from subtracting 2 from 7 is congruent to 1 mod 7.

It's pretty much a mirroring argument of: 2 times 3 is 6, therefore (-2) times 3 is (-6). (-6)+7=1 is the least positive equivalent mod 7 .